# Issue in django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-settings, django-middleware, django-socialauth, djoser

I added `social_django.middleware.SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware`

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'social_django.middleware.SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

Error:

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: WSGI application
> 'Project2.wsgi.application' could not be loaded; Error importing
> module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined somewhere in your settings file the following line:

```py
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'Project2.wsgi.application'
```

That means you must have under your Project2 directory a `wsgi.py` file that declare the wsgi application. It should look like this:

```py
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

More details in the official doc [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/deployment/wsgi/).